# procedure Error on Oracle DB

Tags: sql, database, oracle, stored-procedures

Hi all i'm trying to create the a procedure on Oracle DB, but i'm getting 2 Erros:

```
Error(5,5): PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
Error(6,20): PL/SQL: ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected
```

Here is my CODE:

```
create or replace PROCEDURE Nir2 
IS
BEGIN
    select  DISTINCT AREP.CATALOG_TAG as REPOSITORY, UPPER(AREP.maindb), UPPER(MREP.SCHEMANAME), MREP.MACHINE, ctime AS CREATEDATE, TO_CHAR(MREP.LOGON_TIME, 'DD-MON-YYYY') AS LASTLOGON,
          IF  UPPER(a2i_xcat_dbs.a2i_serverstatus.CATALOG_TAG ) IS UPPER( a2i_xcat_dbs.a2i_catalogs.CATALOG_TAG) 
            THEN
              'LOAD' AS MATCH
          ELSE IF  UPPER(MREP.SCHEMANAME) IS UPPER(AREP.maindb)
            THEN
              'MOUNT' AS MATCH
            END
      from a2i_xcat_dbs.a2i_serverstatus LREP, v$session MREP, a2i_xcat_dbs.a2i_catalogs AREP, SYS.USER$ S
      where UPPER(MREP.SCHEMANAME) = UPPER(AREP.maindb) AND MREP.SCHEMANAME <> 'SYSMAN'
        AND MREP.LOGON_TIME >= ALL (select MREP1.LOGON_TIME FROM v$session MREP1 where MREP.SCHEMANAME=MREP1.SCHEMANAME  )
ORDER BY REPOSITORY, CREATEDATE;
END;
```

**EDIT:**

Here is my new code:

```
create or replace PROCEDURE Nir2 
IS
BEGIN
    select  DISTINCT AREP.CATALOG_TAG as REPOSITORY, UPPER(AREP.maindb), UPPER(MREP.SCHEMANAME), MREP.MACHINE, ctime AS CREATEDATE, TO_CHAR(MREP.LOGON_TIME, 'DD-MON-YYYY') AS LASTLOGON,
          CASE WHEN ( UPPER(a2i_xcat_dbs.a2i_serverstatus.CATALOG_TAG ) = UPPER( a2i_xcat_dbs.a2i_catalogs.CATALOG_TAG) )
            THEN
              'LOAD'
          WHEN ( UPPER(MREP.SCHEMANAME) = UPPER(AREP.maindb))
            THEN
              'MOUNT'
            END AS MATCH
      from a2i_xcat_dbs.a2i_serverstatus LREP, v$session MREP, a2i_xcat_dbs.a2i_catalogs AREP, SYS.USER$ S
      where UPPER(MREP.SCHEMANAME) = UPPER(AREP.maindb) AND MREP.SCHEMANAME <> 'SYSMAN'
        AND MREP.LOGON_TIME >= (select MREP1.LOGON_TIME FROM v$session MREP1 where MREP.SCHEMANAME=MREP1.SCHEMANAME  )
ORDER BY REPOSITORY, CREATEDATE;
END;
```

still i'm getting the following Errors:

```
Error(5,5): PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
Error(6,82): PL/SQL: ORA-00904: "A2I_XCAT_DBS"."A2I_CATALOGS"."CATALOG_TAG": invalid identifier
```

Comment: What's unclear about: *"A2I_XCAT_DBS"."A2I_CATALOGS"."CATALOG_TAG": invalid identifier*

Comment: This table exist, and i'm still getting this error

Answer (score 2):

You can't do "IF" in SQL. Instead, do:

```
Case
  when UPPER(a2i_xcat_dbs.a2i_serverstatus.CATALOG_TAG ) = UPPER( a2i_xcat_dbs.a2i_catalogs.CATALOG_TAG) 
    THEN 'LOAD'
  when UPPER(MREP.SCHEMANAME) = UPPER(AREP.maindb)
    THEN 'MOUNT'
END MATCH
```

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/expressions004.htm#SQLRF20037

Edit:

this ...

```
MREP.LOGON_TIME >= ALL (select MREP1.LOGON_TIME FROM v$session MREP1 where MREP.SCHEMANAME=MREP1.SCHEMANAME  )
```

... might be better as ...

```
MREP.LOGON_TIME >= (select MAX(MREP1.LOGON_TIME) FROM v$session MREP1 where MREP.SCHEMANAME=MREP1.SCHEMANAME  )
```

Answer (score 1):

You have at least two errors in your procedure.

1. `IF` statement is not allowed in the select statement. Use `CASE` instead.
2. You must include `INTO` clause in your select statement, example:

   ```
   create or replace my_procedure
   IS
      l_value1 varchar2(200);
      l_value2 varchar2(200);
   BEGIN
      select 'value 1', 'value 2'
      into   l_value1, l_value2
      from   dual;
    END;
   ```

Comment: Also `IS` keyword is used only with comparing to `NULL`. Otherwise use `=`.

Comment: You still haven't included an `INTO` clause. I added more explanation into my answer. What are you trying to achieve with your select statement? Loop through the results? Display only the first row?